# Disable parent events on click, but allow children to maintain his own events

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault, stoppropagation

I have big upload form, user can drag and drop images here. But when images are loaded, i'm showing button, which on click should link to some page. But this element instead of loading next page, opens file chose window (its parent default behaviour)

So I'm checking, if event has class, if it's true, I'm using `e.preventDefault()`.

And this works better (I don't have image choose window on link click, but also this link will not work - every event is disabled) My question is, how i can enable linking now?

```
// jFiler is a parent - upload form, with event - on click it opens window for file choose - like input field.
$(document).on('click', '.jFiler', function(e) {
    if ($(event.target).hasClass("jFiler-input-done-btn"))  {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

$('.jFiler-input-done-btn').on('click',function(e) {
    // Test works, but this is a link, and it cannot link to another page now...
    alert ('test')
});
```

Comment: Use just `e.stopPropagation();` no need for `e.preventDefault();`. because it will prevent link action.

Comment: The `alert ('test')` reached ??

Comment: I'm not really understanding the problem or what works and what don't. Can you give us more info / a test?

Comment: The alert ('test') is reached.

Comment: .jFiler on click opens upload window : http://filer.grandesign.md/. Inside i have placed <a> element ('.jFiler-input-done-btn) - this element on click, should link to another page, but on click, parent element is fired (opening window for selecting files to upload) - On click this button should link to another page, and not open window for upload.

Comment: @Zakaria, you are right. It works better now (links to another page), but parent event is fired, before linking to another page - for one second, i can see window to choose files, than another page is loaded. So almost fine, but if i could prevent this window opening for 1 sec...

Answer (score 1):

You break the link execution with `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()` in the parent `click` event. You have to just return `true` there.

```
$(document).on('click', '.jFiler', function(e) {
    if( $(event.target).hasClass("jFiler-input-done-btn") ) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: This works similar to e.stopPropagation();, but as i commented above, it works now (link goes to another page) but uplaod choose window appers for 1 sec. Looks like parent event fired, but link also works, so i see this window only to time, when new page is loaded.

Comment: Can you show us you whole `$(document).on('click', '.jFiler', function(e) {});` function?

Answer (score 1):

Just redirect to the other page inside the click event you already attach :

```
$('.jFiler-input-done-btn').on('click',function(e) {
    windows.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});

//OR also

$('.jFiler-input-done-btn').on('click',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, i know about redirect, but it's part of bigger app, and in best case, this shoudl be done by pure html. But thanks for good idea.

Comment: is this possible, that this code sloved problem ? Works fine for me, now on click on button, parent event is not fired...?$('.jFiler-input-done-btn').on('click',function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

Comment: Yes  that true `e.stopPropagation();` inside click event of the link `.jFiler-input-done-btn` should also do the trick.